# Counting INSERT/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert-update, connector-j

I have this sql query:

```
INSERT INTO `Items` 
(`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) 
VALUES (123,321,null) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`id` = `id`, `parent_id` = VALUES(`parent_id`), `name` = VALUES(`name`);
```

I run the query with phpmyadmin, and it returns me right results:

```
0 - No update
1 - Line inserted
2 - Line updated
```

But when I run the query via java/jdbc, the query returns 1-1-2
That is, 1 is returned when there's no insert/update at all.
Any idea? Is it a bug or I just miss something?

UPDATE: Latest connector/j - v5.1.26

UPDATE2: Java code

```
    int ans1 = 0;
    int ans2 = 0;
    try {
        java.sql.Connection c = DbConnector.getConn();

        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ans1 = DbConnector.execute("INSERT INTO `Items` (`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) VALUES (123,9990635,null) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = `id`, `parent_id` = VALUES(`parent_id`), `name` = VALUES(`name`);");
        ans2 = DbConnector.execute("INSERT INTO `Items` (`id`,`parent_id`,`name`) VALUES (123,9990635,null) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = `id`, `parent_id` = VALUES(`parent_id`), `name` = VALUES(`name`);");
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(ans1);
    System.out.println(ans2);
```

Comment: @AndeyP show your jdbc code

Comment: @AndreyP What do you mean by "it returns me ..."? Do you mean return value of `stmt.execute...()` method you used in your Java code?

Comment: Yes, ans1 = 1, ans2 = 1
The first one is ok, cause it's insertion.
The second is wrong, I don't insert/update the first inserted row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to 
[INSERT ON DUPLICATE returns 1 instead of 0 when nothing is changed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39352)
You need to set property "useAffectedRows" to be "true".

Comment: Yep, I see now.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html
When true, the connection reports changed rows instead of found rows.