# Get affected-rows value from mysql DB using Mule 3.5.x+

Tags: mysql, mule, mule-component

On attempting to write to a table, I need to know if the row was updated (new row created or existing row updated) or not. I would have got this value from the affected-rows value.

Previously, the solution would have been to build a class like `org.mule.transport.jdbc.sqlstrategy.SimpleUpdateSqlStatementStrategy` and re-implement it to return the affected-rows value instead of the row itself.

However, it seems like the JDBC transport has been deprecated in favor of the Database connector, and I am finding it hard to track down the code or how to implement the functionality.

SOLUTION :

David's reply got me down the right track! Thanks David.

However, this problem was fixed in the mysql-connector-java in versions 5.1.27 and above.

So, the POM needed to be upgraded.

> mysql
>               mysql-connector-java
>               5.1.27

I was able to achieve the right results using DBCP2 as follows:

> ```
>     <spring:beans>
>          <spring:bean id= "jdbcDataSource" class ="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" name= "Bean">
>           <spring:property name= "driverClassName" value ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />           
>           <spring:property name= "username" value = "root"/>
>           <spring:property name= "password" value = "root"/>  
>           <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local1?useAffectedRows=true"/>
>             <!-- Following properties added for having auto reconnect  mechanism-->
>           <spring:property name= "testOnBorrow" value = "true"/>
>           <spring:property name= "validationQuery" value = "select 1"/>
>          </spring:bean>
>     </spring:beans>   <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" dataSource-ref="jdbcDataSource" doc:name="MySQL_Configuration"/>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector+Reference#DatabaseConnectorReference-Update):

> **target** `#[payload]` The enricher expression used to enrich the current message with the result of the SQL processing.

This should allow you to define an expression that would tell Mule where to store the outcome of the update, which is the number of updated rows.

From [the integration test suite](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.2/modules/db/src/test/resources/integration/update/update-target-config.xml#L11):

```
<db:update config-ref="dbConfig"
           target="#[header:OUTBOUND:updateCount]">
  <db:parameterized-query>update PLANET set NAME='Mercury' where POSITION=4</db:parameterized-query>
</db:update>
```

This sets an outbound property named `updateCount` with the number of updated rows. I'd personally suggest to instead set a flow variable with `#[flowVars['updateCount']]`, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks David, I was able to get the updatedCount, but it is not what I expected since it is different from the values mysql provides. Will follow up with an example.

Comment: I uploaded an working sample to github since there is no space here to add it. 
https://github.com/jackrabb1t/mule-samples/tree/master/example-duplicate-key-insert

The SQL DDL and the DML with the affected-rows values are noted in the README.MD file. 

Please let me know if there is further transformation needed.

Comment: Can you also add to the README what you see Mule logging when you run your application?

Comment: David, I have updated the logs for the run in the README.

In summary, when a record is updated, I get the right value of 2. The problem is that when the record is NOT updated, it should return 0 but returns 1. 

This confuses because I am not able to differentiate between an insert and a record that is unchanged.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with MySQL's JDBC driver: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19043803/387927 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39352

Comment: Great catch David ! I did not find that with searching. I will now look for workarounds and update if I find one.

Comment: I believe that my answer is acceptable because that's the way to retrieve the updated count from the underlying JDBC connector. Could you please accept it?

Comment: Yes David. I am accepting it. Thanks for your help. I was able to figure out the problem, and will update shortly.